# Media queries for CSS class

Tags: html, wordpress, css

Media queries for CSS class

am using .CSSTableGenerator as a css class for table. how to use Media queries for this CSS class file only?

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    body { 
        padding: 0; 
        margin: 0; 
        width: 320px; }
    }

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    body { 
        //width: 495px; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a sidenote: Don't use `device-width`. Use `width` instead. For example an LG G4 has `device-width: 1440px` in portrait mode.

Comment: still not working please guide me..

Answer (score 0):

@media only screen and (max-width:992px){

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px){

}

Use Like this keep Grater size first than lower